# How do I politely ask a teacher to write a reference letter as soon as possible?

Tags: recommendation-letter

I have 3 days left and I totally forgot I could add more than 1 reference letter to my application.

I need this teacher to write me a reference letter as soon as he can... and it feels so rude asking this.

How can I imply that subtly but clear enough for him to understand my situation?

Should I send him reference letters written by other professors to help him quickly find the form and content for the letter he will write?

Comment: Not a duplicate because in his case the teacher forgot to write a recommendation. In my case I forgot to ask him for one.

Comment: @truvaking O.k.

Comment: as an outline summarizing my good points, is my gpa from the 2 semesters, average gpa and ranking enough? what do you mean by giving a way out? " i understand if you cannot find the time to provide a reference letter, but if you do i would greatly appreciate it "

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Please post answers as answers.

Comment: Ar you sure late letters won't be accepted? Personally I've never pressed professors about deadlines (though I have had to remind them sometimes after they clearly forgot). Not worth annoying people who are willing to help my career. Some do it immediately anyway, because they're some kind of insane non-procrastinating-freak-person.

Comment: I wouldn't expect much. If you have three days left, two of them are weekend ...

Comment: Yeah he doesn't seem to respond, and actually I can't find where it was mentioned I could have 3 reference letters. But at least I learned how to politely ask a hierarchally superior person to hurry up :) !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No response from Professor; how should I remind him about writing a recommendation for me?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/32256/no-response-from-professor-how-should-i-remind-him-about-writing-a-recommendati)

Answer (score 2):

Just go and talk to him.Tell him about how much you need the placement and how valuable his recommendation-letter would be to you (don't try to butter him/her).Be frank and kindly request him/her but be brief and direct. Don't worry teachers don't mind it,They want to help you as well.

Comment: i live far from college and i have no idea of his availability...

Comment: You could ask the teacher that gave u  the letter or any other teacher for that matter to provide with is contact info..or visit the university website staff section for details

Answer (score 0):

**What to say.** When you write and ask for the reference letter, tell your teacher when the deadline is and apologize for the short notice. Don't try to be subtle: being polite is about showing that you understand that you're asking for a big favour.

**What to do.** Make sure they have all the information they will need to write your letter (e.g., details of your grades and anything else that's relevant).